# PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu with Filter Width is not coming correct

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

In my facelet, I have one selectOneMenu where I want to apply filter. Filter is working as expected. The only problem is that the width of the filter is not matching the parent.

Below is what I did in my facelet:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="state" filter="true"
    filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
    value="#{manageEmployeeInfoBean.selectedState}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""
             noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems
             value="#{manageEmployeeInfoBean.availableStates}"
             var="aState" itemLabel="#{aState}"
             itemValue="#{aState}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, it looks very odd. How to set the width of the filter as per the parent one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your css file

```
.ui-selectonemenu-filter-container {
    width: 98% !important;
}
```

or 100% if you don't want any padding